# Cannot view static webpage through custom domain via Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I own the domain helpsaverosie.ca and
I've set up the buckets www.helpsaverosie.ca & helpsaverosie.ca and have them both hosting static pages. I've used the dig command in linux to confirm that helpsaverosie.ca is hosted on Route 53 properly.

Trying to view my website I get a DNS lookup failed

Here is my config under Route 53

[image: Route 53]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently delegate your domain to Route 53?  It may take some time for DNS caches to expire your old NS servers and start using Route 53's.  The reason I ask is it's working for me, I see a picture of Rosie the dog.